# How can I make PDFs of Character Sheets from the Character Builder?

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-4e-character-builder

I'd like to be able to see/share my character via PDF or something similar, instead of having to go through whole process of logging and loading. Anyone know a way to capture the pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)Load your Character**

**2)Select Character Sheet at the top Right**

**3)Select Print**: a dialog box should pop up showing your available printers. If you have [Adobe Acrobat Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) (free) installed then you should be able to select Adobe PDF as your printer. This will "print to PDF" creating a PDF file for your character sheet. Another box will pop up where you'll select the location where the PDF will be saved and also the name of the file (defaulting to the character's name). From there you can easily share the PDF file via email or file transfer.

Comment: There are other applications, like PDFill PDF & Image Writer, for those who don't like Adobe (I, personally, don't use Reader).

Comment: CutePDF (http://www.cutepdf.com/) is another free alternative that works in the same way that the poster described for that product.

Comment: I don't have it available as a printer, but know what you are saying, and will look into it. Good answer, and I appreciate it!

Comment: @retrovtx I would reinstall the latest version off the link I provided or download one of the alternatives that these fine gentlemen have listed and you should get some kind of PDF printer as a result.